# How to disable default archive from Maven uploadArchives?

Tags: android, maven-2, android-gradle-plugin

I push apk to custom nexus using the  next gradle script:

```
configurations {
    apks
}

def apk = null
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if ( (variant.name).equals("debug") ) {
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            apk = output.outputFile
        }
    }
}


def isReleaseBuild() {
    return VERSION_NAME.contains("SNAPSHOT") == false
}

def getReleaseRepositoryUrl() {
    return hasProperty('RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL') ? RELEASE_REPOSITORY_URL
            : "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/"
}

def getSnapshotRepositoryUrl() {
    return hasProperty('SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL') ? SNAPSHOT_REPOSITORY_URL
            : "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
}

def getRepositoryUsername() {
    return hasProperty('NEXUS_USERNAME') ? NEXUS_USERNAME : ""
}

def getRepositoryPassword() {
    return hasProperty('NEXUS_PASSWORD') ? NEXUS_PASSWORD : ""
}

afterEvaluate { project ->
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                //beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

                pom.groupId = GROUP
                pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
                pom.version = VERSION_NAME

                repository(url: getReleaseRepositoryUrl()) {
                    authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(), password: getRepositoryPassword())
                }
                snapshotRepository(url: getSnapshotRepositoryUrl()) {
                    authentication(userName: getRepositoryUsername(), password: getRepositoryPassword())
                }

                pom.project {
                    name POM_NAME
                    packaging POM_PACKAGING
                    description POM_DESCRIPTION
                    url POM_URL

                    scm {
                        url POM_SCM_URL
                        connection POM_SCM_CONNECTION
                        developerConnection POM_SCM_DEV_CONNECTION
                    }

                    licenses {
                        license {
                            name POM_LICENCE_NAME
                            url POM_LICENCE_URL
                            distribution POM_LICENCE_DIST
                        }
                    }

                    developers {
                        developer {
                            id POM_DEVELOPER_ID
                            name POM_DEVELOPER_NAME
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    artifacts {
        apks new DefaultPublishArtifact("My Project", "apk", "apk", "final-apk", new Date(), apk)
    }

}
```

The problem is that maven plugin push 2 apk files:
1) some default without classifier
2) my own with my classifier

Default apk is not signet (and I cannot install it to device)

Also I need to use classifier for my own (correct) apk.

How can I disable pushing of default apk?

Comment: Where is the relation to Maven cause this is a gradle file ?

Comment: @khmarbaise this is a using of gradle plugin 'maven' to push apk to nexus